# Difference between Data drop and Data loss

Tags: networking, packet

What is the difference between data drop and data loss?
Any packet dropped should mean that data is also lost with it, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Packet loss occurs when one or more packets of data travelling across a computer network fail to reach their destination while Packet drop occurs when a router intentionally drop the packet. Packet drop is one of the many reasons of data loss.